# Уменьшение персонажа во время анимации

Tags: c#, анимация, unity3d

Настроил анимацию персонажа. Сначала всё было в порядке,но через пару минут вылез баг. Когда мой персонаж начинал двигаться, его спрайт уменьшался в несколько раз. Стал похож на блоху.

До движения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После движения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float JumpHeight;
    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool grounded;

    private bool doubleJumped;

    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position,groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (grounded) 
        {
            doubleJumped=false;
        }

        anim.SetBool ("Grounded", grounded);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && grounded) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
            Jump ();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !doubleJumped && !grounded) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
            Jump ();
            doubleJumped=true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        }

        anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x));

        if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
        else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f,1f,1f);
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
    }
}
```

Update:
После закоментирования этих строчек баг пропадает.

```
if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
 transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
 transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f,1f,1f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В туториале,который я смотрел масштаб спрайта был (Scale)=>1:1:1; Поэтому в коде выше было приведено:

```
if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
   transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
   transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f,1f,1f);
```

Но мой спрайт был слишком мал изначально и мне нужно было его растягивать до размеров побольше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого вместо единиц,нужно было вставить размер (Scale) вашего спрайта.
Конечный код выглядит так(решил отказаться от дробных чисел и округлить):

```
if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
   transform.localScale = new Vector3(8f,8f,8f);
else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
   transform.localScale = new Vector3(-8f,8f,8f);
```

Вскоре появились новые баги,но это уже совсем другая история.

Answer (score 1):

у тебя LocalScale, посмотри в инспекторе объекта какой у него Scale он наверно больше 1

Comment: Ммм?
http://www.floomby.ru/s2/XU76CW/full/

Comment: Я всё понял! Благодарочка. Вот ответ на моё решение.

`if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
transform.localScale = new Vector3(7.510727f,7.604615f,7.510732f);
else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
transform.localScale = new Vector3(-7.510727f,7.604615f,7.510732f);`

Comment: @ArtikSlayer  Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваше решение отдельным ответом, уверен, оно поможет многим вашим коллегам в будущем.

Answer (score -1):

`transform.localScale` - это изменение размера объекта, к которому применен скрипт

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?