# Подрагивание персонажа во время анимации в юнити

Tags: c#, анимация, unity3d

Последний [апдейт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442726/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) повлёк за собой новые непонятные баги.

В чём собственно проблема.После нажатия кнопки влево или вправо (A,D) поочерёдно с интервалом в 2-4 секунды, появляется подёргивание персонажа.

[Видео](https://youtu.be/-9udN2huBa8).

Делал по [туториалу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6ujcvwiHSo) с ютуба.

Ссылка на весь [проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d05zsb4cxrid9i0/Lost%20Penguin%20v.0.0.5.rar?dl=0).(попрыгайте вдаль =D)

Надеюсь на вашу помощь в нахождении решения проблемы. Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Сцена 0.0.5

Comment: Без кода искать ошибки нереально. Вероятно тебе нужно писать в техподдержку юнити.

Comment: Эмм...Код в проекте.

Comment: Там же конструктор который явно скрывает детали реализации под капотом.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробней. Я не понял о каком вы конструкторе и каким образом он скрывает код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 проблемы с персонажем.

1. Смена направления спрайта. Воспроизводится при замедлении персонажа. Причина вот в этом коде:

   ```
   if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
       transform.localScale = new Vector3(8f,8f,8f);
   else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
       transform.localScale = new Vector3(-8f,8f,8f);
   ```

   Здесь Вы сравниваете с точным нолем (Ваши условия вместе обрабатывают ситуации "если число не ноль"), но числа с плавающей точкой (`float` и `double`) могут в реальности иметь значения чуть больше или чуть меньше, и, в том числе, с противоположным знаком (что у Вас и происходит). Это вообще везде так, не только в Unity и C#. И в Unity все как раз немного проще - не нужно задумываться про Epsilon, достаточно проверить на 0 с использованием [Mathf.Approximately()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html):

   ```
   var speed = Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);
   anim.SetFloat ("Speed", speed);

   if(!Mathf.Approximately(speed, 0f))
   {
       //Баг блоха.
       if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
           transform.localScale = new Vector3(8f,8f,8f);
       else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
           transform.localScale = new Vector3(-8f,8f,8f);
   }
   ```

   Если после этого все равно остается проблема, то можно попробовать `if(speed > 0.1f)` вместо `if(!Mathf.Approximately(speed, 0f))`. Предположительно, проблема в том, что при приближении к нулю физика может менять velocity в противоположную сторону на большее число, чем значение встроенного epsilon в классе Mathf Unity.
2. Второй баг связан с застреванием персонажа. Это происходит на стыке коллайдеров пола. Причина ровно та же - неточность чисел с плавающей точкой (так как размер и координаты колайдеров - это числа с плавающей точкой). В данном случае будет достаточно скруглить нижние углы коллайдера персонажа, благо редактировать 2d коллайдер можно прямо в Unity. Можно просто передвинуть уже имеющиеся точки в коллайдере так, чтобы углы не были острыми, этого должно хватить.

Вообще, советую почитать про числа с плавающей точкой. Но, если коротко: *никогда не предполагайте в коде, явно или неявно, что число с плавающей точкой примет какое-то точное значение!*

Comment: Написал,как вы сказали,но [ругается](http://www.floomby.ru/s2/4UPX83/full/)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer Подправил код.

Comment: Неужели,где-то [потерял](http://www.floomby.ru/s2/aUPX5y/full/) скобку?

Comment: `if(!Mathf.Approximately(speed, 0f))` (должно быть две `)` в конце строки).

Comment: Только сам заметил и хотел написать) Но не помогло + округлял полигон [так](http://www.floomby.ru/s2/KUPXs8/full/) и [так](http://www.floomby.ru/s2/eUPXH7/full/).

 P.S.вот что мне пишет один парень с ютуба.   
In your animator you should make sure transition duration on each connection is 0 not 0.1. You should also make sure 'has exit time' is not checked, the connection from any state to jumping has this checked, giving you a big lag.


Hope this helps :)

Comment: Возможно, скорость уходит в больший минус по каким-то причинам. Можете попробовать вместо `if(!Mathf.Approximately(speed, 0f))` написать `if(speed > 0.1f)`, должно сработать. С аниматором я не вижу прямой связи, так как Вы меняете скорость и направление спрайта в коде, а не в аниматоре.

Comment: Пока что работает!!! =D