# Возможная проблема с Collider

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Продолжая набивать [шишки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443290/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) заметил такую вещь. Во время движения ГГ, появился некий дискомфорт. Оказалось, что при достаточном увеличении он не полностью соприкасается с поверхностью.

[image: Пруф]

Итак знатоки. Вопрос. Почему так? Ведь по идее коллайдер земли должен соприкасаться с коллайдером персонажа.

[Проект с кодом](https://www.dropbox.com/s/67f9wta99egnyu2/Lost%20Penguin%200.0.6.5.rar?dl=0)

P.S.Господа модераторы и администраторы. Можно ли в одной теме задавать 2 вопроса близкие по значению?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: какого типа коллайдеры используются в персонаже и в поверхности?

Comment: на персонаже Rigidbody — Collision detection — какое значение? Попробуйте другие значения этого параметра.

Comment: Кстати, проект с кодом я вам рекомендую версионировать с помощью Git и хранить на GitHub или Bitbucket. Так можно было бы показать отдельные классы и не качать весь архив. Да и даже весь качать удобнее из репозитория.

Comment: Про два вопроса: если на них можно ответить одним ответом, то задавайте. Если нет, лучше разделить.

Comment: 1.У персонажа Полигон. У поверхности бокс.
2. На Rigidbody — Collision detection значение discrete.Изменения ни к чему не привели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из скриншота не совсем понятен масштаб.
Если вы изначально взяли маленький масштаб сцены (используются объекты меньше 0.01 единиц в масштабах Unity), то могли столкнутся с фундаментальным явлением, связанным с погрешностью процесса детекции коллизий.

В целом, процесс обнаружения коллизий, даже в режиме "Continous", все равно продолжает быть дискретным (просто частота проверок значительно увеличивается). Это значит, что вероятность абсолютно точного совпадения граней двух коллайдеров в математическом смысле стремиться к нулю. Этот факт вынуждает разработчиков движка задавать допустимые отклонения при обнаружении 
коллизий, которые визуально воспринимаются как микроскопические щели между объектами(реже - как незначительные прохождения граней друг в друга).
"Полет" или "зарывание" в поверхность обуви персонажей и колес автомобилей - это норма даже в современных ААА играх.

Это ответ на вопрос "Почему?". Если нужно, могу посоветовать три варианта лечения.

Comment: Я вас внимательно слушаю)

Comment: Если проблема действительно в том, что я описал выше, то возможны следующие решения: 1) Изменить масштаб всей сцены таким образом, чтобы размер погрешности коллайдеров не имел значения и визуально не просматривался. 2) Если взаимодействие предполагается только снизу (только персонажа и платформы под ним), то можно банально опустить спрайт относительно его коллайдера на величину раздражающего зазора. 3) Если коллайдеры большинства объектов описываются геометрическими примитивами, имеет смысл описать собственную логику взаимодействия объектов с блекджеком и... в обход RigidBody

Comment: Это варианты навскидку?) Без просмотра проекта. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да, я перечислил общие варианты без привязки конкретно к вашему проекту. Когда я сам столкнулся с подобной проблемой, я использовал первый вариант -  изменял масштаб сцены таким образом, что погрешности коллайдера становились незаметны "невооруженным глазом".

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста,как изменить масштаб сцены. Я что-то не пойму.

Comment: Изменить уже созданную сцену довольно трудоемко.  Фактически предстоит вручную пропорционально увеличивать все GameObject и расстояние между ними (Возможно, есть пак для упрощения этой работы).